# FirebaseからStorageに画像をアップロードするときにURLが取得できない

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, firebase

```
func uploadImageToStorage(image: UIImage) -> String? {

        let imageName = NSUUID().uuidString + ".jpg"

        var url: String?

        if let complessionImage = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.1) {

            let ref = FIRStorage.storage().reference().child("profileImages").child(imageName)

            ref.put(complessionImage, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in

                if error != nil {
                    return
                }


                url = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString
            })
        }
        return url
    }
```

これを実行するとref.putの中ではちゃんと変数urlにURLが代入されているのに、returnするときにはnilになっている。
変数urlにURLを代入してreturnするにはどうしたらいいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

あなたが使用している`put(_:metadata:completion:)`は非同期処理であり、その`completion:`パラメータに渡したクロージャー`{(metadata, error) in ... }`は、処理の完了後に起動されます。従って、`return url`を実行した時点ではアップロード処理は完了していないはずですから、`uploadImageToStorage(image:)`は常に`nil`を返す、と言うことになります。

「非同期処理の結果を戻り値として返したい」などのキーワードで検索すれば、様々な記事が見つかるかと思います。探し方によっては「一応動いているように見えるかもしれないが、酷いコード」が上位にヒットすることもあるので注意しないといけませんが、一番確実かつ一般的なのは、完了ハンドラーパターンにすることでしょう。

メソッドに完了ハンドラー引数をもたせ、メソッドそのものからは戻り値を返さないようにします:

```
func uploadImageToStorageAsync(_ image: UIImage, completion: @escaping (String?, Error?)->Void) {

    let imageName = UUID().uuidString + ".jpg"

    if let complessionImage = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.1) {

        let ref = FIRStorage.storage().reference().child("profileImages").child(imageName)

        ref.put(complessionImage, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in

            if error != nil {
                completion(nil, error)
            }


            let urlString = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString
            completion(urlString, nil)
        })
    }
}
```

使う場合は、こんな風に呼び出します。

```
uploadImageToStorageAsync(anImage) {urlString, _ in
    //`urlString`を使用した処理
    //...
}
```

慣れるまでは少しわかりにくいかもしれませんが、非常によく使われているパターンなので、慣れてくればこの方が普通に感じられるようになるかと思います。

(こちらでFirebaseの動作確認ができる環境までは作れていないので、コードについては若干修正していただく必要があるかもしれませんが、考え方は上記の形で問題ないはずです。)

Comment: いろいろなコードで所々見ていた@escapingとcomplesionの使い方を理解することができました。とても丁寧な回答に感動しています。ありがとうございました。